# grep nonascii without pcre

Tags: grep, pcre

I want to grep nonascii characters from a lot of .gz files. However the below does not work on CentOS 7.6 (GNU grep v2.20)

```
$ zcat yyyy/yyyymmdd/filname.yyyymmdd.gz | grep --color='auto' -P -n "[\x80-\xFF]"
$ zgrep --color='auto' -P -n "[\x80-\xFF]" yyyy/yyyymmdd/filname.yyyymmdd.gz
```

This perl search work

```
$ zcat yyyy/yyyymmdd/filname.yyyymmdd.gz | perl -ne 'print "$. $_" if m/[\x80-\xFF]/'
```

But how do I do it on mulitple files like the following?

```
$ zgrep "[\x80-\xFF]"  2020/2020*/filename.2020*.gz
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting LC_ALL=C, the grep -P and zgrep works now.

```
$ export LC_ALL=C
$ zgrep --color='auto' -P -n "[\x80-\xFF]" yyyy/yyyymmdd/filname.yyyymmdd.gz
```